# Using expr over the result of bc

Tags: bash, shell

The following code I was working with throws an error as follows

```
CURRENT_FILE_SIZE="$(hdfs dfs -du -h /user/service-adh_dev/output.dat | awk -F ' ' {'print $1'})"

PREVIOUS_FILE_SIZE="$(hdfs dfs -du -h /user/service-adh_dev/output2.dat | awk -F ' ' {'print $1'})"

COUNT=`expr $CURRENT_FILE_SIZE - $PREVIOUS_FILE_SIZE`
RESULT=`echo "$PREVIOUS_FILE_SIZE* 0.01" | bc -l`

DIFF=`expr $COUNT - $RESULT`
```

throws error as expr: non-integer argument.
Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the values to see just why bash thinks they are non integer?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer expr is suited only for integer valued operations.bc has to be used again in order to find the difference for which the modified script is 
DIFF=`echo "$COUNT - $RESULT"|bc -l`

Answer (score 0):

u can write like this:

```
A=2
B=3
C=$(($A + $B))
echo $C
```

i think it's convenient

Comment: but this is suitable for integer values as mentioned above for float values you can use the bc command for the arithmetic operations